# Create a List of generic list

Tags: java, generics, vector, project

How do I create a list of generic list? I have a Boxcar class that takes a generic argument and a Train class that is supposed to create a list of Boxcars. We are supposed to specify the type that will be in Boxcar in a separate main class, so until then boxcar has to stay generic. The following is the code that I have written. It compiles but in a separate driver class when calling the load method I get the error `The method load(capture#1-of ?) in the type Boxcar<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Person)`

```
package proj5;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

public class Train {

private List<Boxcar<?>> train;
private int maxSpeed;
private int minSpeed;
private String position;
private int numBoxcars;
private int maxNumBoxcars;
private int speed;
private String destination;
private boolean stopped = true;

public Train(int maxSpeed, int minSpeed, int maxNumBoxcars, String position){
    train = new ArrayList<Boxcar<?>>();
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    this.minSpeed = minSpeed;
    this.maxNumBoxcars = maxNumBoxcars;
    this.position = position;
}

public int getMaxNumBoxcars(){
    return maxNumBoxcars;
}

public int getSpeed(){
    return speed;
}

public String getPosition(){
    return position;
}

public int getMaxSpeed(){
    return maxSpeed;
}

public int getNumBoxcars(){
    return numBoxcars;
}

public List<Boxcar<?>> getTrain(){
    return train;
}

public void depart(String destination){
    this.destination = destination;
    speed = minSpeed;
    stopped = false;
}

public void arrive(){
    stopped = true;
    position = destination;
}

public void addCar(Boxcar<?> boxcar, int i){
    if(stopped){
        boxcar.setMaxItems(i);
        train.add(boxcar);
    }
}

public void removeCar(int i){
    if(stopped){
        train.remove(i);
    }
}
```

}

```
package proj5;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Boxcar<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private List<T> boxcar;
private int maxItems;

public Boxcar(){
    boxcar = new ArrayList<T>();
}

public void load(T thing){
    if(!boxcar.contains(thing) && boxcar.size() < maxItems){
        boxcar.add(thing);
        Collections.sort(boxcar);
    }else{

    }
}

public int getMaxItems(){
    return maxItems;
}

public void setMaxItems(int i){
    maxItems = i;
}

public void unload(T thing){
    boxcar.remove(thing);
}

public List<T> getBoxcar(){
    return boxcar;
}
```

}

I hope this better conveys what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but the above code will definetly not compile.

Comment: I think you should be defining classes that use lists, not lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a type in place of `T` and `?` when creating a Generic List.  For example a List of Boxcars containing Strings would look like this:

```
List<Boxcar<String>> train = new ArrayList<Boxcar<String>>();
```

The `?` is an example of a [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html), while a `T` represents a type that is referenced inside the source of `List`.  That point can be tricky to understand without a deeper understanding of Generics, but I wanted to be sure address it for completeness sake. Take a look at [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for more information about how to use Generics inside your code.

Looking at your revised question, I would direct you to this line of code:

```
public class Boxcar<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

and then just below it this line:

```
private List<T> boxcar;
```

This means whatever type you pass to `new Boxcar<type>()` will be carried over to the inner list (and other methods that expect an object of type `T`).

Comment: Alrighty got that thanks. How would I create the List of Boxcars then? With a wildcard? If I try to do anything else it tells me to parameterize Train and I dont think Train class if supposed to take in a generic argument

Comment: You could add Generics to the `Train` class, change `public class Train {` to `public class Train<T> {` then change all occurrences of `Boxcar<?>` to `Boxcar<T>`.  When you instantiate a new object of type `Train` then you will need to pass a type like `Train t = new Train<String>();`

Answer (score 4):

BoxCar which is a generic class:

```
class BoxCar<T>{


}
```

Train class which has a list of Boxcar:

```
class Train {
List<BoxCar<PassTheTypeHere>> = new ArrayList<BoxCar<PassTheTypeHere>>();

}
```

Comment: I find your answer to be more Generic :) +1

Comment: Doesn't that need to be `new ArrayList<BoxCar<PassTheTypeHere>>()`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the wording of your original question it sounds like you want to create a list of boxcars.

Below is all you would need to do.

```
private List<Boxcar> boxcarList = new ArrayList<Boxcar>();
```

Comment: Ignore me, I answered your original, less detailed, question. With your code it is now obvious to me that the other two posters are answering the question you were trying to ask.